# Gradle init example has the error of "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javaslang.λ"

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I am doing a learning of Gradle [with this manual][1], but encounter errors when building this project. And I don't know how to solve it.

**additional information**:
1.the problem appears sometimes and disappears sometimes, and I haven't got a pattern.
2.I've tried gradle version 8.x and 7.x, all have the problem

#### How to re-create this problem

`gradle init` choose

1. application
2. Kotlin lang;
3. multiple projects;
4. Kotlin-DSL;
5. jdk11;
6. no new behavior

```
~/projects/poc-kafka-redirection » ./gradlew build                                                                                                                                             maki.xie@CN-MB-makixie

> Task :app:compileKotlin
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javaslang.λ
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:472)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:433)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:1174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:961)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:867)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1095)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
```

Comment: done fixing. but the button in the edit window to paste and format long logs really sucks takes me quite a while to format it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by window, I always type three backticks followed by none, followed by a linebreak, paste your log, followed by a linebreak and type three backticks. That is \`\`\`none\n<log>\n\`\`\`

Comment: I see. this is waaaaayy better. thanks !

Comment: So what is the real error? Your title mentions `javaslang/collection/HashMap`, but the log only contains `javaslang.λ`

Comment: I think Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javaslang.λ this is the real error, but the stack-overflow doesn't allow me to change the title.

Comment: Changed the title for you

Comment: Which Gradle version are you using?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I don't know the problem but the concrete classes change with each test, and sometimes it is the hashmap, and now it is different.

Comment: Gradle 8.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-10-04 20:52:13 UTC
Revision:     e9251e572c9bd1d01e503a0dfdf43aedaeecdc3f

Kotlin:       1.9.10
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.9 (Eclipse OpenJ9 v0.41.0-release-3ede3b5a4)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.6 aarch64

Comment: The only thing helped me is to remove whole gradle cache directory at $HOME/.gradle/caches

Answer (score 1):

For me, this appears to have been caused by my JVM. My JVM was set to `IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition 17.0.9.0-m1 (build 17.0.9+5)`.

I switched to an open jdk 17.x instance downloaded from Oracle and the problem went away. Specifically, I am now using:

```
java 17.0.9 2023-10-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+11-LTS-201)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+11-LTS-201, mixed mode, sharing)
```